# Controller not found Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner in Symfony 2.8. I have a problem with my controller.

That is my controller:

```
class ExampleController extends ExtraController
{

    /**
     * @ParamConverter("site", class="Bundle:Site", converter="site_slug_converter")
     * @Route("/formacion-example", name="example_web.front.example_training", requirements={"site": "es"})
     *
     * Render the Example form page
     *
     * @param  Site $site
     *
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function example2TrainingFormAction(Site $site)
    {
        $options = ['site' => $site, 'projectId' => $this->get('example.doctrine.project_getter')->getProject()];
        $form = $this->createForm(ExampleTrainingType::class, null, $options);
        $viewData = ['form' => $form->createView()];

        return $this->render('ExampleFrontContactFormBundle:Example:example_training.html.twig', $viewData);
    }
}
```

When I go to my Route www.example.com/es/formacion-example symfony return to me:

> HTTP status: Error 500
>
> Controller: n/a
>
> Route name:example_web.front.example_training
>
> Has session: no

In symfony documentation I cant find a solution.

Thank you! :)

Comment: the error could be coming from missing the site from your route definition, i.e. could you try with @Route("/{site}/formacion-example", ...

Comment: Yeah is right I thought that the ParamConverter do it. Than you man! @ejuhjav

Comment: happy to help, added the same thing as an answer so that this can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding the answer here as well:

i.e. the site parameter was missing from the route

```
@Route("/{site}/formacion-example", ...
```